# Simulate mousedown event on canvas Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I got a basic setup here to test for mouse down on Fabric.js canvas and I am trying to manually trigger a mouse event via javascript (not via mouse click) to simulate a click on the canvas.

HTML

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<a id="testClick" href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a>
```

Javascript

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

$("#testClick").click(function() {
   var e = jQuery.Event("mousedown", {
     pageX: 700,
     pageY: 300
   });
   $('#c').trigger(e);
});

canvas.on({"mouse:down": function() {
   alert("you clicked me");
}});
```

So far there is nothing that enables me to simulate this, help appreciated.

Comment: The trigger is outside the enclosure so 'e' cannot be reached. Place var e; outside the enclosure.

var e;
$("#c").click(function() {
   e = jQuery.Event("mousedown", {....

Comment: @LeroyThompson what enclosure you refering to? they are in same enclosure of the click();

Comment: Hold on a moment, let me refer to a jsfiddle...

Comment: Yes ehhemm canvas variable has to be part of jQuery definition.

https://jsfiddle.net/zo98p72L/10/

jQuery frameworks therefore trigger could be used on jquery selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

`var canvas` variable has to be part of jQuery definition. But I see it's is part of fabric. Therefore .trigger() cannot be used on that definition.

.trigger() is jQuery framework therefore it could be used on jquery selected element$.

**UPDATE**

https://jsfiddle.net/zo98p72L/14/

**Since this has been voted up 2 times** - I decided to post this.

Comment: Hmm i thought the Event and trigger functions just invoke the event you designate. Didn't know they needed to be part of other libraries to invoke them. Thanks ill start looking in different direction then.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire the events directly on the Fabric canvas object, passing arguments as a second parameter:

```
var fCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

fCanvas.on("mouse:down", function(e) {
  alert("you clicked me here ("+e.pageX+","+e.pageY+")");
});

fCanvas.trigger("mouse:down", {
    pageX: 700,
    pageY: 400
});
```